# How to use textbox module from fabricjs in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fabricjs

I'm working to add a textbox to the canvas using fabricjs in a rails project.

> [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jafferhaider/51u08n39/92/) of what I want to achieve.

---

I'm adding the text this way:

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var helloWorld = new fabric.Textbox('Hello, World!', {
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  top: 5,
  left: 5,
  fontSize: 16,
  textAlign: 'left'
});

canvas.add(helloWorld);
```

I got this error from Chrome's console:
`Uncaught TypeError: fabric.Textbox is not a constructor`

---

[Here](https://250mils-transfer.s3.amazonaws.com/fabric05182015.js) you can find all the code from fabricjs v1.5. However, line 1 says:

```
/* build: `node build.js modules=animation,interaction,gestures,image_filters,text,itext,textbox,shadow minifier=uglifyjs` */
```

**Is there a workaround for this to use the textbox module in a rails project?**
BTW, I have never worked with node before.

Any guide to the right direction will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Now it works.**

I only updated fabricjs from version [`1.5`](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/releases/tag/v1.5.0) to [`1.6.0-rc.1`](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/releases/tag/v1.6.0-rc.1).

You can find the latest fabric's distribution files from  [kangax/fabric.js](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/tree/master/dist)